# $http.post().then vs $q library?

Tags: angularjs, q

It is my understanding that when you do something like `$http.post(...).then(...)` in angularjs, it returns a promise.  The confusing part to me is that `$q` is a promise library and if `$http.post(...).then(...)` creates a promise for me, is the `$q` library necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just dealing with respose via `$http.post(...).then(...)` you don't need to use `$q` service directly.

But angular uses `$q` [internaly](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/http.js#L1173) when you are calling `$http`.

Also note that [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is not a separate library, it is just module inside angular core.

Answer (score 3):

So $q can be used for a lot of things. Another example would be webworkers which dump javascript execution onto different threads. You could create a service that wraps that in promises. One of my favourite things to do with $q is something like this:

```
$q.all([httpRequestOne, httpRequestTwo, httpRequestThree]).then(function(data){ ... });
```

This allows me to wait until all 3 http requests are done before I run code.